# Extracting text from html file gives attribute error

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the text from an htm file on my jupyter notebook. I first read the file using: 
`with open('Materials.htm') as file b:
file3=b.readlines()
file3=''.join(file3)`

Then, I parse the file and use get_text().

```
Stock_page=BeautifulSoup(file3, 'lxml')
   for movers_name in Stock_page('td',style="text-align:left;"):
       movers=list()
       movers.append(movers_name.get_text())
       print(movers)
```

This code does print the list but also give the

> AttributeError:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

I want to put this in a for loop to read different files but with the error it doesn't work. Does anyone know what am I doing wrong? Than you!

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the file object just as it is to BeautifulSoup and parse it as HTML.

```
with open('Materials.htm','r') as f:
    Stock_page = BeautifulSoup(f, "html.parser")
```

Comment: I was doing the ''.join() because using with open gives me a list of strings which I can't feed to beautifulsoup. I tried using "html.parser" instead and it worked. Thank you for the help!